# Error in handling Dictionary while using streamlit

Tags: python, dictionary, streamlit

I am creating a fake news detector sort of website. I have successfully made connection with the API.
i have also successfully got the output from the API. The problem arrises when i implement it in streamlit

my code -->

```
import requests
import streamlit as st
API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/hamzab/roberta-fake-news-classification"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer 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"}

def verify(text):
    def query(payload):
        response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
        return response.json()

    tp = query({
        "inputs": text,
    })
    return tp

st.title("Demo")
text = st.text_input("Enter the news Article")
with st.expander("Expand to read the news"):
    st.write(text)
if st.button("Verify",type="primary"):
    output = verify(text)

    label1 = output[0][0]['label']
    label2 = output[0][1]['label']
    score1 = output[0][0]['score']
    score2 = output[0][1]['score']
    progress1 = st.progress(val = score1,text = label1)
    progress2 = st.progress(val = score2 ,text = label2)
    st.text("working")
```

the error->

```
File "D:\FakeNews\.venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "D:\FakeNews\app.py", line 23, in <module>
    label1 = output[0][0]['label']
```

example output from the API-->
[[{'label': 'FAKE', 'score': 0.9990308284759521}, {'label': 'TRUE', 'score': 0.0009691992308944464}]]

Comment: Please share the actual error message. Here, you've only shared the Traceback (WHERE the error occurred, not WHAT error occurred).